# I have a error in discord.py (purge command)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have this Python code for discord.py rewrite:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clean(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            llimit = ctx.message.content[10:].strip()
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=llimit)
            await ctx.send('Cleared by <@{.author.id}>'.format(ctx))
        await ctx.message.delete()
else:
    await ctx.send("You cant do that!")
```

But every time i get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Can someone here help me?

Comment: `llimit` is a string, you need an int. `int(llimit)`

Comment: @abccd can you send me the code with the int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat single argument callables (like `int`) like [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) for the purpose of declaring arguments.  I also changed your permissions check to be handled automatically by a [`commands.check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#checks)

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clean(ctx, limit: int):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
        await ctx.send('Cleared by {}'.format(ctx.author.mention))
        await ctx.message.delete()

@clean.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You cant do that!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `limit` argument of the `purge` function takes an integer as a value

Try doing something like this

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def clean(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            llimit = ctx.message.content[10:].strip()
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(llimit))
            await ctx.send('Cleared by <@{.author.id}>'.format(ctx))
        await ctx.message.delete()
else:
    await ctx.send("You cant do that!")
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with `content[10:].strip()` but if you're trying to ignore the `!clean` part of your command you are using too large of a number. `content[7:]` would suffice

Comment: My prefix is shb!, the only wrong thing is the int that i forget... Thanks bro and pls sorry for any English errors

Answer (score 0):

Also to make the bot check errors you can even do like this

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clean(ctx, limit: int):
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
        await ctx.send(f'Cleared by {ctx.author.mention}')
        await ctx.message.delete()

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You cant do that!")
```

Also this way it will remove errors of every command so that will be better

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way I've been able to do this, hope it helps!

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def purge(ctx, limit: int):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
```